# Uncaught PHP Exception Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\MappingException

Tags: php, symfony, orm, doctrine, twig

I'm trying to develop an application using Symfony v3. I've created the entitites with the autogenerator provided by Symfony with a configuration.yml placed separately. For example, for Sponsor entity is:

```
   WebBundle\Entity\SponsorPage:
    type: entity
    table: null
    repositoryClass: WebBundle\Repository\SponsorPageRepository
    id:
        id:
            type: integer
            id: true
            generator:
                strategy: AUTO
    fields:
        title:
            type: string
            length: '255'
        titleOrganizers:
            type: string
            length: '255'
            column: title_organizers
        titleSponsors:
            type: string
            length: 255
            column: title_sponsors
        titleCollaborators:
            type: string
            length: 255
            column: title_collaborators
    lifecycleCallbacks: {  }
```

Doctrine commands: `app/console doctrine:mapping:info` and `doctrine orm:validate-schema` shows everything fine in the log.

All the structure is placed in a dev environment, but when I try to access via browser does not show anything, but locally everything works fine.

I've read every post with same issues and no one works for me. The log error display is: 
[image]

I would appreciate any help!

Thanks!

Comment: please read the error message, to me it sounds your config is not correct/updated for your dev env, it doesn't sound like a entity definition issue to me.

Comment: @LBA I've read many times the message and I have no answer, that's why I am asking here. I don't know what kind of config is not correct, everything seems fine, but clearly is there something wrong.

Comment: then please rephrase your question, take out the entity definition but copy the error message in a readable/copyable fashion and post your config. do you have session.write rights on your remote server? did you clear the cache for --env=prod etc?

Comment: @LBA I don't know what is wrong, could be something in Doctrine (as message shows) or something in my configuration, php version, etc. I've cleared cache and I have correct rights in the server and the issue persists

Comment: please post your config_*.yml config files

Comment: I've solved the issue. Finally, it seems to be a permissions error. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I've finally solved my own issue. It seems to be a permissions conflict. I've solved using `chmod 775` in all project in my CentOS server.

Comment: don't recommend to do that, seems far too much permission, check e.g. Symfony doc on required [file permissions](http://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/file_permissions.html).

Comment: @LBA yes of course now I have to depurate to restablish permission and only give them to the needed folders (seems to be /cache and /log), but for the moment it's a nice approach

Comment: Did you finally review the folder permissions?